# parse the command output and store it in the dicitonary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

I have created a class to execute a command and return the entire output of the command. I'd like the store the output in the dictionary like below.

```
dict = {'ID': '*1', 'Type': 'udp', 'Destination': 'x.x.x.x', 'stats': 'RTT=1' , 'Return code' = 'OK', 'Last Run' = '0 seconds ago' }
```

command output :

```
IPSLAs Latest Operation Summary
Codes: * active, ^ inactive, ~ pending

    ID           Type        Destination       Stats       Return      Last
                                               (ms)        Code        Run
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    *1           udp       x.x.x.x            RTT=1       OK          0 seconds ago


from test.ssh import Ssh

    class  crypto:
        def __init__(self, username, ip, password ,router):
           self.user_name = username
           self.ip_address =  ip
           self.pass_word = password
           self.machine_type = router

        def sla_output(self, interface):
           command = 'show sla summary'
           router_ssh = Ssh(self.ip_address)
           result = router_ssh.cmd(command)
           return result
```

Test script :

```
from test.networks.router_parser import *

routerobj = crypto('user', 'ip', 'password', 'cisco')
status = routerobj.sla_output()
print (status)
```

Comment: So...what have you tried to store the results in a dictionary? Also, it looks like your `sla_output` method is improperly indented.

Comment: @VictorC. I tried split function. But i'm not sure how to split it as "-----" is command for the all the key value pair

Comment: Could you split it on the `--------` (maybe using a RegEx like `\-+`), then split each side based on the whitespace?